# Is there text to speech engine available for urdu for and android

Tags: android, text-to-speech, urdu

I want to know if there any google text to speech engine exist for URDU speech
i have latest text to-speech 3.3 for android and there is no URDU available in the list.
any body know how to speech URDU text in android.

Answer (score 1):

The Answer is no , not as of yet however developer like my self are researching into A.I speak engines that in short fall will be able to translate English language into spoken Urdu word

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and quickest answer is "its in process"

The reason why I am saying this, if you take a look on Google Translate web page, I just typed `What languages I can speak` the system have an option to play the URDU translation.

https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=ur&text=what%20language%20I%20can%20speak

[image: What Languages I can speak]

Comment: are there any updates on this is there a tts available for urdu in android or flutter, any api that I could use.

Comment: Its now functional here: https://translate.google.com/?sl=ur&tl=ur&text=%DA%A9%DB%8C%D8%A7%20%DB%81%D9%88%20%D8%B1%DB%81%D8%A7%20%DB%81%DB%92&op=translate